# How to get the URL of the captured image

Tags: jquery, html, image

I have created a page where i am trying to capturing the image using my phone cam this much is possible using `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>`. But my next step is to uppload the image to a specific record. For that i want to get the url of the captured image. How can i get the url of the captured image?
Is there any method on in jquery to capture the image url or location where the image get saved after capture. Please guide me the best way for the solution.

Comment: http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

Comment: At this stage, the image does not _have_ a URL. You need to submit the form, and use for example PHP to upload the image to your own server. Only then does the image have a url / file name you can store in a record.

Comment: then how can i get the image file before upload. Bec i am working in salesforce (force.com ) platform i want to upload the image there itself .. the how can i get the image ..